# Why is String.toLowerCase undefined in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In the Chrome console, String.toLowerCase returns undefined. However in Firefox, it does not.

What's the reason for the difference?

```js
var body = $("body");
body.append(new String(String.toLowerCase).toString());
body.append("<br>");
body.append(String.prototype.toLowerCase.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `String.toLowerCase` is not part of any standard. Firefox supports it, Chrome does not.

Comment: @Pointy MDN says that chrome supports String.prototype.toLowerCase(), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

I think the issue is that no string is being defined to operate on. See working snippet answer below.

Comment: @DLowther yes, but `String.toLowerCase` and `String.prototype.toLowerCase` are two different things. Firefox definitely has a `toLowerCase` function directly on the String constructor in addition to the prototype method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.toLowerCase` is one of the *Generics* that Firefox has allowed for String, Array (and possibly other). They are not defined in any ECMAScript standard and are considered deprecated by Firefox and will be removed.

Extracted from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> String generics are non-standard, deprecated and will get removed near future. Note that you can not rely on them cross-browser without using the shim that is provided below.

See also:

- [Introduction of Generics in Firefox's JS 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6)
- [Deprecation announcement](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/non-standard-array-string-generics-have-been-deprecated/) (Not sure how much support the site has from Mozilla, so take this one with a grain of salt.)
- [Deprecation warning implementation ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1319926)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? Either of these work fine in chrome for me.

```js
let body = $("body");
let str = 'STRING TO LOWER';
body.append(str.toLowerCase());
body.append("<br>");
body.append("ALL CAPS".toLowerCase());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Is this what you are trying to do?" I don't think so. I think they just want to understand why the generic String.toLowerCase() is implemented in Firefox but not in Chrome, and they're not actually trying to convert a string to lowercase (in fact, I'd presume they already know how to).

Comment: That's correct @BoltClock. I was caught out because I wasn't aware that string generics existed on Firefox, so one of my scripts broke unexpectedly.